# How to detect the option is selected from scroll bar or value is entered in textbar on form submission?

Tags: php

I am working to perform if else condition on form submission (POST Method) by detecting whether (the scroll option `projectcode` is selected AND the `date` is entered or not) OR (the value `modifieddate` is entered or not).

Based on the detection i am executing my if else conditions but things are not working.

I have a form inside in file `dashboard.php`

```
<form action='dashboardentry.php' method='post'>

    <label>Project Code: </label>
    <select name='projectcode'>
        <option value=''>Select...</option>
        <option value='COP-INT'>COP-INT</option>
    </select>

    <label>Date: </label>
    <input type='date' name='date'>

    <label>OR</label>

    <label>Modified Date: </label>

    <input type='text' name='modifieddate'>

    <button type='submit' name='delete'>Delete Entry</button>

</form>
```

I basically want to check whether to perform delete operation via project code and date variable value or via modified date in my database (has entries of hours spent) and for this i done below things.

In the file `dashboardentry.php`

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

    if(isset($_POST['projectcode']) AND isset($_POST['date'])){

    }elseif(isset($_POST['modifieddate'])){

    }else{

        echo "Please Enter either Project Code or Modified Date to delete Entry";

    }
?>
```

But my problem is that this if else is not working properly as per my expectation. plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe check if values aren't not empty like this :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

    if( isset($_POST['projectcode']) &&
        !empty($_POST['projectcode']) &&
        isset($_POST['date']) &&
        !empty($_POST['date'])){

    } else if(isset($_POST['modifieddate']) && !empty($_POST['modifieddate'])){

    } else{

    echo "Please Enter either Project Code or Modified Date to delete Entry";

}


?>
```

Comment: Yes remove one of them. Either isset or empty.